# regex problem with helicon ape on windows server 2008

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, helicontech

I have the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.php\?(.*)  /$2.php?shop=$1&$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.php        /$2.php?shop=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/$  /index.php?shop=$1 [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$   /index.php?shop=$1 [L,NC]
```

The result of which *should* redirect the following:

```
www.site.com/Sells 
    -> /index.php?shop=Sells [works] 

www.site.com/Sells/menu.php?Cat=1 
    -> /menu.php?shop=Sells&Cat=1 [failing] 
    -> /menu.php?shop=Sells [which is 'wrong']
```

The last example *should* get matched by rewrite [1]...

I have tested the rules with the regex tester shipped with ape and found that escaping `?` and `.` don't seem to work.  I am a little flummoxed and would appreciate anyone who 
could shed some light on why this escaping is not working.

Loads of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QSA flag was missing! it appends the query string and I forgot to put it in!!!

The double slashes I added as preview was not showing the single ones!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.php\?(.*)  /$2.php?shop=$1&$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.php        /$2.php?shop=$1 [NC,L]
```

Too much escaping. Change `\\.php` to `\.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to escape the \ that is meant to escape the . (you have \. which is read as \ and any letter/symbol)